# Употребление слова "якобы"

Tags: выбор-слов

Допустимо ли использование "якобы" в следующих предложениях? Если нет, то почему?

1. "...возбудить уголовное дело за **якобы** препятствование поставкам продовольствия..."
2. "...это стало бы достойным ответом на **якобы** отказ снять санкции..."
3. "...заявления представителей ветеринарных ведомств о **якобы** угрозе птичьего гриппа..."

Answer (score 1):

Союз ЯКОБЫ можно использовать во всех приведенных примерах.

**Пояснение**

**Якобы - книжное слово, используется в различных стилях: художественном, научном, публицистическом и т.д., ограничений нет.**

**Из словаря:**

ЯКОБЫ. **I. союз.** Книжн. (соединяет предл. и чл. предл.). Выражает сомнение в достоверности сообщаемого. Уверяет, я. он звонил. Слух идёт, я. зарплату повысят. **II. частица.** Указывает на предположительность высказывания, на сомнение в его достоверности. Говорит, что серьги я. бабушкины. Прочитал я эту я. умную статью. Ты слышала о моём я. романе с ним?

**Примеры:**

Витгенштейн убедительно разрушает иллюзию, что математику **якобы** можно отделить от физической реальности. [В. А. Успенский. Витгенштейн и основания математики (2002)]

Один из арабов тряс каким-то удостоверением, пытаясь запугать нас тем, что он **якобы** из полиции. [Сати Спивакова. Не всё (2002)]

Мы с товарищем поднялись в горы и зашли в чегемские леса, **якобы** охотиться на крупную дичь. [Фазиль Искандер. Сюжет существования (1965)]

Comment: Интересно, полезно, но нет конкретного ответа на конкретно поставленный вопрос

Comment: Спасибо. я дополнила ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, частицу "якобы" здесь уместно использовать только в 1 и 3 случае. Действие уже свершилось, но из-за мнимых причин.
Во 2 случае -  "...это стало бы достойным ответом на якобы отказ снять санкции..." – предложение имеет смысл, только если слово  "якобы" убрать вообще.